# Blazor WASM (Client Side Only) - How to make HTTP Request to different APIs?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, blazor, webassembly, .net-5

So I'm coming from Xamarin world trying to build a Blazor App.  And I'm struggling with a high level understanding of why Blazor Apps ( client side only ) cannot make a basic HTTP get call to say google.com or any other http get/post call to different resources/urls?

Can someone break it down for me, am i  crazy?  how would i ever implement maps.google.com or other http request I'm going to need to make.

I do notice anything with a package, like SendGrid or B2C or Cosmos Nuget Packages seem to work fine... how do they get around the different domain names ?

Can i simply say on my webserver : (in English)  - allow requests to google.com and someoneElsesApi.com
or would i have to contact google and have them allow my Blazor app to make calls?

Just really struggling with how to use Blazor Client Only PWA app if it cant connect or call to anything else on the web... seems pointless if a Blazor app cannot make any http calls to other services.

Comment: You can't make requests to servers that you don't control. It would be a major security issue if a browser could call to any server in the world via code at the drop of a dime. Look up CORS and why it's important.

Comment: You should be able to call third-party public web API endpoints using HttpClient. [This documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1) shows how to create an HttpClient with your own host, but you should be able to use that for any third-party. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I did read up on Cors obviously not enough for me to understand why Browser is so different than any other application i can do this with.   In a console app i can use HTTP request on http://www.google.com and get a response... in Blazor(or browser i guess), it's a huge security issue.. why the diff?

Comment: As Andy mentioned, adding CORS to my own API allowed access from my Blazor app... But i cant go ask other 3rd party APIs to add my domain to thier CORS

Lex - I read the link and see the line "HttpClient and JSON helpers are also used to call third-party web API endpoints."..   maybe I'm not seeing it correctly, but nothing else in that paragraph or article discusses 3rd party APIs.... I think that line is just kind of a note

should following work(cant think of example api to test)? HttpClient c = new HttpClient();    await c.GetFromJsonAsync("Some-allow-annonymus-3rdPartyAPI-URL");

Comment: @John Blazor WASM doesn't make any HTTP calls by itself, the browser does. All browsers are built to refuse to connect to any endpoint not specified through a CORS policy. Comparing a desktop app like Xamarin Forms to an SPA that runs in the browser (that's what Blazor WASM is) will only confuse you. You should compare it to other SPA frameworks instead, like React, Vue or plain JavaScript

Comment: Thank all for your helpful comments, i am coming from Xamarin world, new to a Blazor Project and that was causing the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so yes... I found an Public Open API to test a request against, and it does work from a Blazor WASM (Client only).  More specifically the below works just fine..

@inject HttpClient HttpClient
...
string responsString = await HttpClient.GetStringAsync("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/5");

The problem i was having which seems confusing:

Both

1. Blazor WASM
2. Xamarin Forms apps
   can both call an open public Web API just fine from HTTP Client.

But...
When I create an ASP.NET core API and publish it allowing anonymous access in azure,

1. Xamarin Forms can call that API
2. Blazor WASM cannot call it unless i specify CORS correctly in the Web API

So with my inexperience with Blazor WASM i assumed it could not do this.. while Xamarin can.  So this changes to ... how is it that the Web API i created in Azure + ASP.net Core Web API - just allows the Xamarin App to call it (without CORS specification)... while CORS Must be set correctly for a Blazor WASM?

Comment: Comparing Xamarin to Blazor isn't helpful. Xamarin Forms doesn't run on a browser. Blazor WASM does. It's the *browser* that actually makes the HTTP request and refuses to connect to other APIs. You configure CORS to tell the browser that it's OK to connect to those other APIs.

Comment: "CORS Must be set correctly for a Blazor WASM" because CORS is a security feature of JavaScript (browser). If you use Blazor Server App you won't have any CORS issues.